# Do most people understand the meaning of yellow traffic light?

Tags: usa, traffic

This happened to me several times. When I approached a traffic light that turned yellow, I stopped my vehicle as according to [Chapter 4](https://www.stateofflorida.com/traffic-signals/) of the Florida Driver's Handbook, a yellow traffic light means “**Stop if you can. The light will soon be red.**” However, the driver behind me did not seem to be happy and honked at me to express his/her frustration. They seem to view the yellow light as “go before it turns red if you can, " which contradicts what I read from the Florida Driver's Handbook.

I did not check the meaning of yellow light in every state/country but I guess they may have a similar meaning. Do most people understand that yellow light means "stop if you can" instead of "go if you can"? It seems to me that an accident could happen if two drivers do not share the same understanding; namely, when a driver stops the car at a yellow light while the driver behind him/her does not want to stop.

Comment: In general, if you get rear-ended, then the person who hit you is typically found to be at fault because they were not traveling at a safe distance from you, or were not paying attention.  Exceptions to this are if you do something stupid/dangerous to cause the accident.  The only way this might affect who is at fault at a traffic light is if you slammed on the brakes the very moment the light changed to yellow, when you were not at a safe stopping distance before the intersection.

Comment: Here in the UK, we don't have yellow lights.  Instead, we have amber ones.  Opinions vary on the meeting ranging from: stamp on the brakes to floor it and try to get through.  Another difference shared by just a few other countries is red and amber to indicate that green is coming soon.

Comment: @badjohn Generally it's in countries where manual transmissions are more commonplace, it gives drivers a couple of seconds to push down on the clutch pedal and put the car into gear.

Comment: @badjohn semantics. Amber or yellow or orange all mean the same thing, and look the same too. Just different words for the same light

Comment: @jwenting Of course, I was just joking but it is useful to know if you come here.  People will be puzzled if you talk of a yellow light.

Comment: @Crazymoomin Makes sense but manual transmissions are predominant in most of Europe and yet only a few have the red and amber signal.

Comment: @jwenting - On UK railways, the signal colours possible are red, **yellow**, and green. Referring to yellow as 'amber' will identify a person as a railway ignoramus.

Comment: Gosh, we’re all deathly concerned about some hypothetical other person’s inability to understand color names, huh?

Answer (score 14):

Your understanding is correct. In most states steady yellow means "Stop, if it is safe to do so". I think this  probably true for all states but I'm too lazy to check 50 websites.

> Do most people understand that yellow light means "stop if you can" instead of "go if you can"?

Both. In practice many drivers will assess if you can safely make it through the intersection before the light turns red. Technically that's not the intent of the law but people don't like sitting in front of a red light.

Ignore the honk.

Comment: I think you can add most countries, as it is also the norm in those European countries of which I have learned the rules.

Comment: Except if OP had to brake very intensively, making it unsafe (for the driver behind). In this case, horning was correct. So it's not "stop if you can" (as OP says), it's "stop if you can stop safely" (as the answers rightfully says).

Comment: Exactly: don't attempt an emergency stop when there is no real danger.

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of the yellow light is to make sure people don’t get hit with a fine (or points on their license) if they go through a red light that turned red just when they were about to cross the relevant line.

Basically it means “you have to stop, but if it’s unsafe to do so/too late for you to stop, you won’t be fined like you would for running a red light”.

Timing of the yellow light is usually defined by code, based on legal speed limits, taking into account reaction time and safe stopping distance at that speed.

Yes, you should stop, but only if you can safely do so (safely for you, your passengers, and the vehicles behind you), so no sitting on the brakes or emergency stop, just a regular stop.

Many people do indeed consider that yellow lights mean the opposite: “quick, it’s going to turn red, speed up to cross before it does”, and they’re likely to not like it if you don’t follow their “rules”.

Unless you stopped too abruptly, there is no valid reason for them to honk and you should just ignore it.

Of course if the intersection is complex (different lights for different lanes/directions), or in places where you can still turn right at a red light (with or without a stop, depending on jurisdiction), then the situation may be different. If you stopped when you shouldn’t (the yellow wasn’t for you) or remained standing at the red light when you are allowed to turn, then you would be in the wrong.

Comment: The best sample on how it is **not** supposed to be done was shown in the 1984 film [Starman](https://youtu.be/g3WtvzmKCQQ): 'I watched you very carefully. Red light, stop. Green light, go. Yellow light, go very fast.'

Answer (score 5):

> They seem to view the yellow light as “go before it turns red if you
> can, " which contradicts what I read from the Florida Driver's
> Handbook.

As far as the law is concerned, there is no requirement to try to stop on a yellow, even if they are able. As long as they enter the crosswalk or enter the intersection before the light turns red, they have not violated the law. So while "go before it turns red if you can" might not be the recommended practice, if they actually manage to enter the crosswalk or the intersection before the light turns red, it is legal.

According to [this article](https://jarlstrom.com/PDF/Exhibit_1_FINAL_An_investigation_of_the_ITE_formula_and_its_use_R14.pdf), page 19-23 (page 20-24 in the PDF), only the states of Iowa, Michigan, Mississippi, Nebraska, New Jersey, Oregon, Virginia, and Wisconsin have a "restrictive yellow". All other states, including Florida, have a "permissive yellow".

The specific Florida statute on the yellow light is in section [316.075](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0300-0399/0316/Sections/0316.075.html)(b)(1):

> Vehicular traffic facing a steady yellow signal is thereby warned that
> the related green movement is being terminated or that a red
> indication will be exhibited immediately thereafter when vehicular
> traffic shall not enter the intersection.

This is simply a warning, and there is no command or requirement here. The section on red light is in section 316.075(c)(1):

> Vehicular traffic facing a steady red signal shall stop before
> entering the crosswalk on the near side of the intersection or, if
> none, then before entering the intersection and shall remain standing
> until a green indication is shown; however:

Here, the requirement is, once they face a red light, to stop before entering the crosswalk on the near side of the intersection (if there is such a crosswalk), or before entering the intersection (if there is such a crosswalk). If the person has already entered the crosswalk (if there is such a crosswalk) or intersection (if there is such a crosswalk) before the light turns red, then they cannot be in violation of this section.

Of course, the fact that it might be legal for them to try to make it past the line while the light is yellow, before it turns red, if you were not in front of them, does not give them the right to honk at you for stopping, which you are fully entitled to do on a yellow light.

Comment: "As long as they enter the crosswalk or enter the intersection before the light turns red, they have not violated the law." But that's not always the case. That's the definition of a permissive yellow, which as you said only covers 42 states plus DC. Restrictive yellow means you must exit the intersection before the light turns red.

Comment: @user71659 so like in the Netherlands where yellow means "stop if you can do so safely" (red meaning STOP! NOW!).

Answer (score 4):

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

France has actually three meanings to a yellow light :

---

- The standard Green --> Red cycle with a solid yellow light

In which case the law (Article [R412-31](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006842154/2022-04-06) of the road code) states :

> Tout conducteur doit marquer l'arrêt devant un feu de signalisation jaune fixe, sauf dans le cas où, lors de l'allumage dudit feu, le conducteur ne peut plus arrêter son véhicule dans des conditions de sécurité suffisantes.

All translations are mine

> All drivers must stop at a solid yellow traffic light, except in the case where, when the light turns yellow, the driver can't stop anymore in sufficent safety conditions

---

- Blinking yellow light on the bottom of the light box (where a green light is normally) :

Equivalent to a green light, but turned on when there is a particular danger ahead.

In which case, the driver is required to follow the right of way rule and not the standard assumption of priority at a traffic light.

---

- Blinking yellow in the middle

It happens if the traffic light is broken, or it is sometimes enabled at night because there are such low traffic volumes that traffic lights are deemed useless

It means that the intersection is not under traffic light regulation at all, and right of way must be followed at all times

Answer (score 0):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

To quote [the relevant section of the Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/light-signals-controlling-traffic)

> AMBER means ‘Stop’ at the stop line. You may go on only if the AMBER appears after you have crossed the stop line or are so close to it that to pull up might cause an accident

Note the last clause - if stopping ***might*** cause an accident, you shouldn't stop. Not 'would' cause an accident, not 'could' cause an accident' - 'might'. This is a very loose rule!

You should always be aware of how close the vehicle behind is. The fact that they are too close to stop safely doesn't make it OK for you to cause an accident - in general, "I was technically in the right" is not a good argument for knowingly causing an accident...

Comment: correct.  And never overestimate the capabilities of the vehicle or its occupants behind you in this. Their brakes might be near minimum legal status, the driver may be distracted or impaired. Better safe than sorry. Worst case, a red light ticket is likely cheaper and less of a hassle than the aftermath of an accident, especially an accident in which there are injuries or worse.